# How to get count by array of values using MongoDB and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to get sum of count of document using MongoDB and Node.js. I am explaining my code and document below.

```
var finalOut=[
    {
        "location": "NEW DELHI",
        "nos_of_fos": 15,
        "login_id": [
            "9619300317",
            "9619300343",
            "9619300338",
            "9619300351",
            "9619300322",
            "9619300316",
            "9619300323",
            "9619300328",
            "9619300341",
            "9619300309",
            "9619300310",
            "9619300329",
            "9619300353",
            "9619300356",
            "NORTH@oditeksolutions.com"
        ],

    },
    {
        "location": "North West Delhi",
        "nos_of_fos": 6,
        "login_id": [
            "9619300355"
        ],

    }
]
```

The above is my input. I am explaining my code below.

```
finalOut.forEach(function(listItem, index){
                    Feedback.collection.aggregate([
                        {
                            $match: {
                                login_id: {
                                    $in: listItem['login_id']
                                }
                            }
                        },

                    ])
                    .toArray((cerr,cdocs)=>{
                        console.log(cdocs);
                    })
                    finalOut[index]['total_remarks']=cdocs;
                })
```

Here I need the total count of all login_id arrays value which is present inside `feedback` document.

Comment: If you have MongoDB 4 or above you can use the $count operator or $sum in earlier versions

Comment: @JamshidAsadzadeh:Can you just help me to add that part.

Comment: What version of MongoDB do you have?

Comment: @JamshidAsadzadeh : `3.0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `forEach` for asynchronous operations:

Here I will use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library but you can use any library that you like.

```
async.forEachOf(finalOut, (listItem, index, callback) => {
    Feedback.collection.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                login_id: {
                    $in: listItem['login_id']
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $count: ‘theCount’
        }
    ])
    .toArray((cerr,cdocs)=> {
        finalOut[index]['total_remarks']=cdocs.theCount;
        callback();
    })
}, err => {
    // here you can access the filled `finalOut` object
});
```

Comment: I tried also this before getting callback result all loop getting finished so there is no record in `total_remarks` but output is coming in console.

Comment: You would have to use promises and/or async/await. I’m outside I’ll help you in couple of hours if no one answers by then